# Update Node.js & Cordova in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to update nodejs and cordova.

In got the latest version of nodejs and installed it into c:\program files\nodejs

However there is some conflict when i try to install cordova

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Npm shows the version installed in visual studio and closes:

> c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\3614fb17\taco-toolset-6.3.1\node_modules

I tried most of the solution found on stackoverflow and many others on google nothing. manual change of the version in config.xml will simply crash the app and thats all.

How to update it?

Comment: Got any of the error output?

Comment: When i try npm update cordova -g , or anyother package nothing happens. I installed node v10. All the npm packages are set to go in taco-toolset, i set the npm path to new node, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution as far.

I gave up on visual studio and using my good old Edit Plus IDE and using cordova in command line to build / run etc.